# Flutter Release apk installation in emulator

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I am trying to install release apk in emulator , it gets installed but crashing while opening. But its working in mobile devices. Is this possible to work in emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Use flutter run --release in terminal to run in release mode

Comment: That's fine, But i need to run my apk in another system emulator.

Comment: Do you use firebase? Crashes maybe due to different sha1 keys too.

Comment: No, I just tried with Hello world example, Which also facing this.

Comment: what's the min sdk version in gradle and are you signing with user created jks file?